# How to add a 2nd view as a Tab Bar View (iPhone SDK)

Tags: iphone, sdk, objective-c-2.0

So before I've managed to work with TabBarViewControllers and create an application using them. However every time I do so the view acts as my main view. This time around I want my TabBarView to be my second view in my application

E.g

First window has a bunch of buttons, when I click one of these buttons I want the second view to show up. This view includes a TabBarViewController.

The farthest I've gotten is to have the button show a view but for some reason it won't show my TabBar view!

Here's the code for my button

```
- (IBAction)showEvents:(id)sender {

EventsViewController *controller = [[EventsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"EventsView" bundle:nil];
controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

}

Any of you guys able to help?

Comment: Not really, your code doesn't reveal anything about how you create the view of EventsViewController so it is pretty much guessing for now. Could you show the initialization code from EventsViewController and/or give a detailed explanation of its nib?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway, I found a solution and it was actually quite simple. After creating the Outlet for the TabBarController and linking it together with File's Owner all I had to do was add

self.view = tabViewController.view;

On the viewDidLoad method

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just in the EventsViewController add the following code in viewDidLoad:

```
UITabBarController *tbc = [[UITabBarController alloc] init]; 
tbc.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: vc1, vc2, ..., nil];
```